# Error with Typescript custom type declaration

Tags: reactjs, generics, typescript

I have the following type-declaration written for [r-dom](https://github.com/uber/r-dom):

```
/// <reference types="react" />

declare module 'r-dom' {

    interface IRDOMFacade extends React.ReactDOM {
        (component: React.Component<any, any>, properties?: Object, children?: React.ReactElement<any>|Array<React.ReactElement<any>>): React.ReactElement<any>
    }

    var r: IRDOMFacade

    export = r
}
```

A sample component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as r from 'r-dom'

export default class Application extends React.Component<{},{}> {

  render() {
      return r.h1('Hello World')
  }

}
```

The above component has no type errors. But when I try to use r as a function I get type error:

```
r(Application)
```

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Application' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'Component'.   Property 'setState' is
>   missing in type 'typeof Application'.

I am curious what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because first argument of r was a class/constructor having signature `React.Component<any, any>` rather than an instance of `React.Component<any, any>`.

So switching to the following fixes the error:

```
interface IRDOMFacade extends React.ReactDOM {
    (
        component: new (...args: any[]) => React.Component<any, any>, 
        properties?: Object, 
        children?: React.ReactElement<any>|Array<React.ReactElement<any>>
    ): React.ReactElement<any>
}
```

I will keep this open for few days in case someone has a more idiomatic solution.